# How to create a session for authentication with fetch API in JS

Tags: javascript, authentication, session, fetch, session-cookies

> I have two URLs. The first one is for login post request and the second URL is to call for a json. I can not get the json file from URL, if I am not logged in. How can I create a session so I can do more than one post request or alternatively how can i use JWT or set-cookie for authentication?

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
const login_url = "https://www.example.com/login"
const json_url = "https://www.example.com/users/anastasia"
const data = {"username": "my_username", "password": "my_password"}
const otherParm = {
   headers:{"content-type": 'application/json'},
   body:JSON.stringify(data),
   method:"POST"
};
fetch(login_url, otherParm)
//.then(data=>{return data.json()})
.then(res=>{
    console.log(res.headers.get('jwt'))
   })
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

> The response is:
> distinct_id: 156841653654e68w,
> jwt: e1616er5hw16e35hw6e5h6eth

```
fetch(json_url).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (obt) {
   console.log(obt);
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.error('something went wrong with retrieving the json file');
   console.error(error);
});
```

> The response is: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: After you get your JWT, include it in the headers of your second call. Something like `{"Authorization" : "Bearer " + jwt }`. Refer to the documentation of the API you are using.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyThille! Apparently I can't use jwt for re-authentication in this website. I might go with sessions. My assumption is based on : If i do the same procedure in the browser, i can see that post request does not use jwt for authentication. Is it possible to create a session?